# Sphero's modal views with iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, sphero-api

I've noticed the Sphero modal views don't cover the entire parent view on an iPhone5 and I can't change the nibs.  Is there a property I can set to make the modal view cover the entire parent view?

[image: ColorPicker modal view]

Also the No Sphero Connected modal view doesn't look right for Portrait (RUINoSpheroConnectedViewController_Portrait)

[image: RUINoSpheroConnectedViewController_Portrait]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not expected behavior, and we've noted it, and we're working on ironing it out.

For now, you can fix the issue with the colorpicker view by setting the bounds of the view to the bounds of the parent view in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller: `colorPickerView.bounds = self.view.bounds`.

Comment: Constraints giving you problems? I feel ya.

Comment: They are!  As a newbie, it's very frustrating to do 3/4 of you UI in IB and the other 1/4 in viewDidLoad :)